# Understanding GAGA correspondence from some basic questions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

On page 78 of Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry," we encounter the following correspondence:

Proposition 2.6: Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. There exists a natural, fully faithful functor $t: \mathfrak{Var}(k) \rightarrow \mathfrak{Sch}(k)$ from the category of varieties over $k$ to schemes over $k$. For any variety $V$, its topological space is homeomorphic to the set of closed points of $\operatorname{sp}(t(V))$ (where $\operatorname{sp}(t(V))$ denotes the underlying topological space), and its sheaf of regular functions is obtained by restricting the structure sheaf of $t(V)$ via this homeomorphism.

In other words, one can associate a scheme to a variety since $t$ is faithful.

Now, **let $k=\mathbb{C}$**. Then one can also associate to a scheme  a **complex analytic variety**, via the well-known **GAGA theorem**. GAGA also tells us that many things are equivalent between the scheme category and the complex analytic category; in fact, the correspondence between them is a fully faithful functor. We denote this functor by $G$. (I believe $t^{-1}$ aligns with the GAGA correspondence, as suggested by references on page 439 and page 81-2.14-d in Hartshorne book; however, this is not the focus of this post.)

However, several important questions arise, which may require additional conditions on the involved schemes:

**Question:**

1. Is $H^i(X, F)\cong H^i(G(X), G(F))$ true, where $F$ is some good
   sheaf on the scheme $X$?
2. If $X$ is birational to $Y$, then is $G(X)$ birational (or
   bimeromorphic) to $G(Y)$?
3. Suppose $f: X\to Y$ is a morphism of schemes, and the generic fiber
   $X_{\eta}$ is rational, i.e., birational to $\mathbb{P}^n_{K}$,
   where $K$ is the function field of $X$. Then is the general fiber of
   $G(f): G(X)\to G(Y)$ birational to
   $\mathbb{CP}^n:=\mathbb{C}^{n+1}/\sim$, where the general fiber
   means the fiber over an analytic Zariski open subset of $G(Y)$.

Any comments and recommended references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn’t any fully faithful functor take isomorphisms to isomorphisms?

Comment: @Chris any *functor* takes isomorphisms to isomorphisms.

Comment: So point 2 is trivial

Comment: @Chris   Yes, Philosophically  speaking, everything is the same between those two category. But rational map (and birational map)  is not morphism of the involved categories.